# react hook form not able to click radio button for the first time, getting null

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Using react-hook-form is pain for me , all the things works as expected for me except radio button , when i click radio button for the first time it does not get clicked , but when i re click it it works , i am trying to solve the error from a long time but unable to do it.

```
 <div >
      <p>Radio Button</p>
      <span className="form__error">
        {' '}
        {errors.types && 'This is a required field'}
      </span>
      <div >
        <label htmlFor='a'>
          <input
            {...register('types', {
              required: true,
            })}
            id='a'
            type="radio"
            value="a"
          />

         
            a
        
        </label>
        <label htmlFor='b'>
          <input
            id='b'
            type="radio"
            {...register('types', {
              required: true,
            })}
            value='b'
          />

        
            b
          </h3>
        </label>
        <label htmlFor='c'>
          <input
            id='c'
            type="radio"
            {...register('types', {
              required: true,
            })}
            value='c'
          />

         
            c
          </h3>
        </label>
        <label htmlFor='d'>
          <input
            id='d'
            type="radio"
            {...register('types', {
              required: true,
            })}
            value='d'
          />

         
          d
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is potentially related to this issue found on react-hook-form github page issues [[Preact, RHF 7.0] Radio inputs not working](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/4604)

The reasoning given is:
Preact is currently handling "ref callback" different than React. At the time "ref callback" is triggered, radio inputs are not attached to the page yet. When collecting and merging DOM reference of multiple radio inputs in a radio group, method "register" of react-hook-form v7 performs a safe filtering to check if those radio inputs exists in the page or not by using "document.contains(ref)" therefore the previous DOM references are cleared and only the last "ref" is available.

I was having a similar issue using react-hook-form (v7.45.1) and one of the responses worked for me:

**Solution**

```
const { register } = useForm();

const customRegister = (name, options) => {
  const { ref, ...field } = register(name, options);
  
  const customRef = (...args) => {
    setTimeout(() => ref(...args));
  }
  
  return { ...field, ref: customRef };
}

// Just use "customRegister" instead of "register"

<input {...customRegister('test')} id="one" />
<input {...customRegister('test')} id="two" />
<input {...customRegister('test') id="three" }/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have faced the same issue, I don't know the cause, but I solved this problem by using setValue function from react hook form;

There an example from [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/elastic-alex-n7z2s3?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopqhn45000a3b872pbyt67j%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopqhn4500033b87lcc35sb6%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopqhn4500073b87bohw4yo0%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopqhn4500093b87862hbsrt%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clopqhn4500033b87lcc35sb6%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopqhn4500033b87lcc35sb6%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clopqi2gd008y3b87adie6h7m%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.tsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopqi2gd008y3b87adie6h7m%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.css%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopqpo700d0u3b87ho2vvmga%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clopqhn4500093b87862hbsrt%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopqhn4500083b87ab1royxu%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopqhn4500093b87862hbsrt%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clopqhn4500083b87ab1royxu%2522%257D%252C%2522clopqhn4500073b87bohw4yo0%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopqhn4500073b87bohw4yo0%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopqhn4500043b87nkw5ivm0%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopqhn4500053b87wq0voihr%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522build%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopqhn4500063b87nfg2b59h%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522preview%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clopqhn4500043b87nkw5ivm0%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D):

```
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, setValue } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      fruit: "banana",
    },
  });

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValue("fruit", e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Select your favourite fruit</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="banana">Banana</label>
          <input
            {...fruitRegister}
            onChange={handleChange}
            id="banana"
            type="radio"
            value="banana"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="apple">Apple</label>
          <input
            {...fruitRegister}
            onChange={handleChange}
            id="apple"
            type="radio"
            value="apple"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="mango">Mango</label>
          <input
            {...fruitRegister}
            onChange={handleChange}
            id="mango"
            type="radio"
            value="mango"
          />
        </div>
      </form>

      <div id="result">
        <h2>Selected value</h2>
        {JSON.stringify(result)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```